Can you use a binary outcome variable in a longitudinal latent-growth mediation model
I am wanting to create a LGCM in which I am assessing whether two latent factors (the intercept and slope) mediate the relationship between a continuous predictor and binary outcome variable but am not sure whether this is possible?  Does anyone have any advice/ signposting?

Can you edit your post to explain LGCM?
